# jQuery on() not working through ajax call but does work when called independently

Tags: jquery

This is a strange one..

Essentially I have a three stage form which automatically saves it status.

When you click the first submit button it loads the second stage through ajax.

If you refresh the page it reloads the second stage (but NOT through ajax) using session data.

On the second stage of the form is a button.. when the user clicks it I want to call some jquery and make an alert.

My code is as follows:

```
    $(document).on("click","#submity",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
alert('lol');


    });
```

This is included between a document ready statement in an external js file loaded on the initial page load. It is loaded after the jQuery library, and that is being imported correctly.

When the second page is loaded by ajax, clicking the button does absolutely nothing. When loaded directly it alerts as expected. I cannot for the life of me work out why?

Other questions on SO seem to pertain to delegating with on() but as far as I am aware I have done it correctly, and similar setups work elsewhere on the site..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: id must be unique try with a class

Comment: @ThomasClowes check for other event assigned to DOM...check for code when ajax call response ...can we have code that you have used.?

Comment: Dipesh could you clarify what you are syaing and which doe you want to look at?

Comment: isn't your .on code launched after the ajax is end ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an object between `document` and `#submity` with a click handler that blocks the event bubbling, either with event.stopPropagation() or return false;

Your code works like this: the click event is created on the clicked object (`#submity`) and passed up the DOM hierarchy until it reaches the `document` where jQuery calls your event handler. If that chain is canceled somewhere in the middle your handler will never be called.

Are you perhaps assigning click event handlers during or after the ajax call?

Without code it's going to be difficult to diagnose. Can you post a link?

Comment: Its quite difficult to show code because the JS file contains thousands of lines of 'other' js which is used at different points on the site. In terms of "Are you perhaps assigning click event handlers during or after the ajax call?" could you perhaps clarify that statement? Thanks

Comment: Ok... now I am just confused - I moved the anippet of code (above) to the very top of the JS file, just below the document ready check and it works.. for seemingly no apparent reason. Does that help as regards an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind your .on() event for dynamically loaded button after it was loaded on a page, or use .live() wich is obsolete. So do binding stuff in ajax success callback

Comment: Could you clarify.. i thought the whole premise of delegating with on() was that you DONT Have to do this?

Comment: NEVER use .live(). If you have an older version of jQuery you can use .delegate() but in version 1.7+ you should ALWAYS use .on().
The code Thomas uses should work. Only the selected element (document) must exist when setting the event handler.
see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have read through the docs myself. THe fact that it works when the page is loaded directly suggests that all is in order.. but it isnt :)